# How can i integrate this function?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

How can i integrate this? I tried by parts but it didn't end well.
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-5x}-e^{-10x}} x \, dx$$

Comment: This type of integral is known as a [Frullani integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe we have that
\begin{align}
\frac{e^{-5x}-e^{-10x}}{x} = \int^{10}_{5} \frac{e^{-tx}}{x}\ dt\sim -\int^{10}_5e^{-tx}\ dt
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_0\frac{e^{-5x}-e^{-10x}}{x}\ dx =&\ -\int^\infty_0\int^{10}_{5}e^{-tx}\ dtdx\\
=&\ \int^{10}_{5}\int^\infty_0e^{-tx}dxdt = \int^{10}_5 \frac{1}{t}\ dt \\
=&\ \log 10-\log 5= \log 2. 
\end{align}

Comment: I have never seen the use of an asymptotic integral to evaluate another integral. I do not know much about asymptotics, so how is this justifiable? I am aware of the use of the Frullani integral to evaluate this though. Can you provide a resource for this?